# ¿Cómo podria quitar las variables globales del siguiente código?

Tags: python, variables

¿cómo podría quitar las variables globales de este código?, quiero hacer esto porque he leído que no se recomienda el uso de estas pero no se como dejar de implementarlas ya que son muy útiles.
¿En vez de usar variables globales que podría implementar?

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x500+400+10")
root.title("Lineas")
root.resizable(0,0)

Canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg = "white",width=600,height=500)
Canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
x = None
y = None

def draw(event):
    global x
    global y

    if x != None and y != None: 
        Canvas.create_line(x,y,event.x, event.y,width=20,capstyle="round",fill="red")

    x = event.x
    y = event.y 

def reset_line(event):
    global x
    global y

    x = None
    y = None

root.bind("<B1-Motion>",draw)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",reset_line)
root.bind("<A>",lambda _:Canvas.delete("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las maneras sería utilizando una clase:

No utilizo `tkinter` así no garantizo que lo haya hecho todo bien, pero la lógica de las clases viene a ser que a todas las variables pertenecientes a la clase se puede acceder mediante `self`

```
import tkinter as tk 

class nombre_de_la_clase(object):
    """Esto es tu clase, ponle el nombre que quieras"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Esto es tu initializador, solo se ejecuta una vez, al crear la clase
        Crea tus variables y binds de inicio aquí dentro"""
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x500+400+10")
        self.root.title("Lineas")
        self.root.resizable(0,0)
        self.Canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg = "white", width=600, height=500)
        self.Canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.root.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)
        self.root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.reset_line)
        self.root.bind("<A>", lambda _:Canvas.delete("all"))
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.root.mainloop()

    def draw(self, event):
        """Documenta qué hace esta función o método"""
        if self.x != None and self.y != None: 
            self.Canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y, width=20, capstyle="round", fill="red")
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y 

    def reset_line(self, event):
        """Documenta qué hace esta función o método"""
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

clase_instanciada = nombre_de_la_clase()
```

Lo he testeado por encima y funciona, aunque no me gusta tener el `root` dentro de la clase, pero bueno, creo que primero deberías de intentar aprender como funcionan las clases en la programación enfocada a objetos.

Bonus: Este enlace dispone de diversas formas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17466968/2707901